# Junit result is not consistent always in AEM

Tags: java, maven-3, aem, junit5, sling-models

I have the below JUNIT code.
Case 1
I get Nullpointer exception error when I tried to execute it in Eclipse and I get all test cases passed when I run it in command prompt.

Case 2 - I get Nullpointer exception error error sometime even when I ran the code in command prompt with to execute. Maven command used - mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle

I guess it is because of the resource I am loading. But it this resource is always there in eclipse build path.

Junit code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import com.techcombank.core.constants.TestConstants;
import com.techcombank.core.testcontext.AppAemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContextExtension;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith({ AemContextExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class })

public class FeatureListModelTest  {

    private final AemContext ctx = AppAemContext.newAemContext();
    
    FeatureListModel featureModel;
    

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {

        ctx.load().json("/content/mysite/en/featurelist.json", "/content");
        ctx.addModelsForClasses(FeatureListModel.class);
        featureModel = getModel("/content/jcr:content/root/feature");
    }
    
     @Test
        void getFeaturePath() {
            final String expected = "/content/dam/mysite/logo.jpg";
            assertEquals(expected, featureModel.getFeaturePath());
        }
     
     private FeatureListModel getModel(String currentResource) {
            ctx.request().setAttribute(WCMMode.class.getName(), WCMMode.EDIT);
            ctx.currentResource(currentResource);
            FeatureListModel fm = ctx.currentResource().adaptTo(FeatureListModel.class);
            return fm;
        }
}
```

Any idea on case 1 and case 2. Why is this consistent happen ? In fact I restarted eclipse and my windows machine but no luck.

Comment: In which line do you get the NPE? Can you show the stack trace?